# Rails 5.2.2 Sprockets::ConversionError (could not convert "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" to nil)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I just upgraded my rails 4 app to the latest rails 5.2.2. Everything went smooth until I booted my app and it throws this weird error

```
Sprockets::ConversionError in Home#index
could not convert "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" to nil
```

Upon some investigation I noticed it was originating from `image_tag` helpers. I fired up the console to inspect and true there's something weird happening.

I have an image called `banner.jpg` inside my images asset folder. In my rails console I ran

```
 helper.image_path("banner.jpg")
```

Which throws the error

```
Sprockets::ConversionError (could not convert "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" to nil)
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction, I'm I missing something. My current research on this error has not yielded any results. Using `ruby 2.6.1` and `rails 5.2.2`. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally resolved this. The issue on my app was I had a `fonts` directory inside the `app/assets` directory in my old rails 4 app. Apparently at the time I had read some article that adviced me to place my fonts there. It seems with the new rails 5 anything that is not an image, js/css file inside the `app/assets` directory will cause this or a similar error. Removing my `fonts` folder from the `app/assets` directory cleared the error.

Comment: How did you end up serving your assets through sprockets?

Comment: You mean fonts??

Comment: Yes I do mean fonts, right now I'm having issues with font's from a gem with sprockets 4.